# How is Populist badge calculated?

Tags: support, badges

According to the badge page, [Populist badge](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/badges/39/populist) is calculated as follows :

> Highest scoring answer that outscored an accepted answer with score of more than 10 by more than 2x. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

Can someone clarify what is meant by "more than 2x", its 2x of what score ?

Asking this question because I thought I might be eligible to earn this badge for this question "[Lightning datatable column value misaligned](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/271270/lightning-datatable-column-value-misaligned)", knowing that my answer score is more than 10 and has outscored the accepted answer but I may be missing something here.

Thanks in advance for clarifying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I read the definition:
*If there is an accepted answer, with a score of more than 10, and you provide an answer which achieves twice this score, you will be awarded the Populist badge.*

If you look at the list of the 17 answers awarded the Populist badge, you will see some good examples of this:

[Target inner elements of standard Lightning Web Components with CSS](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/246887/target-inner-elements-of-standard-lightning-web-components-with-css/252852#252852) - Accepted answer score: **12** (More than 10? Yes),  Populist answer score: **33** (More than double 12? Yes)

[Call Apex class method on the fly (dynamically)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1035/call-apex-class-method-on-the-fly-dynamically/1036#1036) - Accepted answer score: **21** (More than 10? Yes),  Populist answer score: **45** (More than double 21? Yes)

Comment: Ah its clear now, thanks.